# Deleting unused nested records updating model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is 2 models: BeautySalonCategory and BeautySalonService:

```
class BeautySalonCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :beauty_salon_services, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :beauty_salon_services, allow_destroy: true

end

class BeautySalonService < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :beauty_salon_category

end
```

In controller:

```
    def category_params
        params.require(:beauty_salon_category).permit(:name, beauty_salon_services_attributes: [:name, :cost, :duration, :id] )
    end
```

I use category_params to create a new BeautySalonCategory object with related BeautySalonService objects. It works. Also I want to do the following thing: when an BeautySalonCategory object is being updated, than unused related BeautySalonService objects will be deleted (for example, a category has 3 related services, than I update this category with only 1 service from those 3 ones - I want that other 2 services will be deleted). Can you help me?

```
def update
    @category = business.beauty_salon_categories.find(params[:id])
    @category.update!(category_params)

end
```

Comment: Are you asking when you are about to update the Category, keep the received nested BeautySalonService and delete all others for that Category ?

Answer (score 0):

You need add the `:_destroy` field to permited params:

```
params.require(:beauty_salon_category).permit(:name, 
  beauty_salon_services_attributes: [:name, :cost, :duration, :id, :_destroy])
```

And add to the partial of beauty_salon_services:

```
<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
<%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove" %>
```

I think that this will do the trick.